# EditStrap: afterChangeValue not fired

Tags: jquery

I am testing testing this [Editstrap jquery plugin](https://www.editstrap.com/index.html). I would like to use it in my upcoming project. The documentation says that **afterChangeValue** is

> A function that will be executed after a value changed successfully.

It does not get fired in my code:

```
$('#txt-control').editstrap({

    type: 'text',
    emptyText: 'Enter your name' ,
    afterChangeValue: function(editable,newValue){
         alert('Value has successfully changed');            
    }

})
```

[See this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: A fiddle would be nice.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feed back. I'll try to create a fiddle though I do not know how to upload external libraries

Comment: Use jsfiddle. You only need the uri of the library.

Comment: Unfortunately this library that not have a public url (like cdn, if that is what you mean) . I download its file and include it in my application via script tag

Comment: Maybe it is the missing `;` in the end of your code. But without a fiddle I can't help you.

Comment: I have added a jsfiddle (it only has the bare necessities)

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: Never mind. I have updated to the latest version. And now it is working